# Android - How to have multiple pages/section in a fragment? (No viewPager)

Tags: android

For better Understanding check this sample design

[image]

What I want to achieve is a sign up mechanism. Where when a user done filling page 1 and click next then

- The next button stays at the fixed location
- The indicator do an animation and change
- The two field ("Full Name" and "Select your gender") get swapped out by the fields of Page 2.

**Those fields in both pages will be in same Fragment, viewModel and repository**. This is a simplified version of what I want to achieve.

I am a beginner in Android & already watched tutorials of viewPager2 but I'm pretty sure it won't help here. One thing I can do is, to use "visibility hide & show" but I don't think it would be the best practice. **Hiding and showing will also not help in manually swapping the pages**.

So, how to implement multiple pages/section in a single fragment?

Comment: And why specifically is ViewPager not usable here?

Comment: @ArtieVandelay Those videos were showing me it works same as recylerView and basically it inflate views. Am I wrong?

Comment: Hint: Even if a `ViewPager` is not usable, you'll have to add multiple views here & handle / manage their `visibility` depending on the indicator click.

Comment: @kallis I'm not very experienced with ViewPager so take this with a grain of salt, but from what I can tell from the docs, a ViewPager doesn't inflate the views for you. It just looks at the views in the adapter, and you're responsible for providing and inflating them. A RecyclerView, on the other hand, will tell you when to inflate a view, and when to bind data to it, making you less in control but allowing it to be more efficient if you have a lot of data.

Comment: @DarShan No other way?

Comment: As @ArtieVandelay said, its either ViewPager or RecyclerView or as I said, `View`'s visibility handling.